# How to map a DB column name that is a Java reserved word to a Java model object field using MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

So I have a table `CoolTable` with 2 columns: `something` and `short`.

And my model class named `CoolClass` reflects it with 2 fields: `something` and `_short`. `short` is a Java reserved keyword, so the field had to be prefixed with the underscore.

Now my mybatis mapper XML uses `CoolClass` like so:

```
 <select id="getStuff" resultType="CoolClass">
    SELECT * FROM CoolTable
</select>

<insert id = "insertStuff" parameterType = "CoolClass">
    INSERT INTO CoolTable (something, short)
    VALUES (#{something}, #{short})
</insert>
```

Now, when I `getStuff` and `insertStuff` only `something` column gets retrieved and inserted. `short` is always null.

I searched through all the MyBatis documentation but couldn't find anything relevant to help with this case.

How can I go about mapping `short` column to `_short` field of class?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using a ResultMap like so:

```
<resultMap id="coolResultMap" type="CoolClass">
    <result property="_short" column="short"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getStuff" resultMap="coolResultMap">
    SELECT * FROM CoolTable
</select>
```